# Terraform depends_on aws_iam_policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies, terraform-aws-modules

I have a module that create some aws policy from json files.
Terraform plan return an error when it try to attach the new resources (policies) to the role it is creating.

```
The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply
```

This is ok, so I tried to use depends_on on the module that create the new resources (policies), but I still have the same error.

here my module:

```
module "admin" {
  source = "./my_repo/admin"

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_policy.common,
    aws_iam_policy.ses_sending,
    aws_iam_policy.athena_readonly,
  ]

  policies = [
    aws_iam_policy.common.arn,
    aws_iam_policy.ses_sending.arn,
    aws_iam_policy.athena_readonly.arn,
  ]
```

In the module ./my_repo/admin I have a file with this code (here I have the error)

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "me" {
  for_each   = toset(var.policies)
  role       = aws_iam_role.me.name
  policy_arn = each.value
}
```

What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: var.policies is e list of resources (iam policies).
How can I get arn of every single policy?

Answer (score -1):

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many policies will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the for_each depends on.

Comment: This is the error return by terrafom